# Screen Tearing on Linux Mint Mate with Intel Graphics

Tags: video, intel-graphics

I'm experiencing screen tearing with Lint Mint Mate 19.1.

Running `lspci | grep VGA` prints

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

Edit: Motherboard appears to be a Canonical-certified [HP 18E7](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201506-18433/) (this is a shortened output of running `dmidecode -t 2`).

Comment: Added the motherboard model, thanks!

Comment: A search at http://forums.intel.com/s/global-search/screen%20tear%20Linux did not reveal anything specific for tearing with the eight year old discontinued Xeon E3-1200 https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/59137/intel-xeon-processor-e3-family.html .

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall [xserver-xorg-video-intel](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xserver-xorg-video-intel).

Comment: Tried, it didn't solve the problem. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Wd you please take a look at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374405 ?

Comment: I tried the instructions in "post 7", i.e. adding `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf`. Also didn't solve the problem. But these instructions look specific to NVidia? The file `/sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset` doesn't exist after rebooting, FWIW.